# How to guarantee rows order

Tags: sql-server-2008, order-by, data-integrity, checksum

I'm trying to implement a methodology to check the integrity of a restored database. It goes as following:

1. Create a snapshot of the database.
2. Gather various metadata:

   1. On disk used space.
   2. Name of tables.
   3. Number of rows in each tables.
   4. ...
3. Generate a cryptographic hash using the data in each table.

My issue goes with the 3rd step to generate the cryptographic hash. I plan to read each row one by one and update my hash with the data they contain. But for my check to match I have to make sure that the row order stays the same.

How can I make sure to always get the same row order, assuming that I don't know upfront the table structure and on what column I can order on.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-agg-transact-sql is your friend

Comment: `CHECKSUM_AGG` hardly qualifies as cryptographic strength though, performing a simple CRC routine and returning a 4-byte result. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221210/ amongst other discussions. Though IIRC that is the only hash available as a convenient aggregate function in TSQL (without using CLR code to implement your own).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ORDER BY` is the only way to guarantee order. If you have a unique key (primary key, unique index) then order by this, otherwise you'll need to order by all the columns in the table. If you have multiple unique keys and one of them is the clustering key for the table (or the first part of a larger clustering key) then ordering by that would be most efficient. As you don't know ahead of time what table definitions you have you will need to work out what candidate sorting keys you have by checking the contents of `sys.indexes` and friends.